# Cant get tinymce to display

Tags: html, css, typescript, tinymce, angular5

Im trying to install tinymce to use with my text editor to allow the user to have a text box just like the stack overflow one. I cant get it to display though

ive put this in the head of my index file

```
<script src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'></script>
<script src='https:https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'> 
</script>
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
 <script>
      tinymce.init({selector:'infotextarea'});
 </script>
```

then in my info page ive put

```
                      <textarea id="infotextarea">Your content here. 
                     </textarea>
```

can anyone explain why its not displaying

Comment: Perhaps you can make a JS Fiddle or CodePen that shows the issue?  Without running code it will be hard for folks to know why this is failing.  I will note you appear to be loading TinyMCE 3 separate times - I have no idea why you would need to do that - loading it once should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that at the time you run the tinymce.init function, it is not yet rendered and there is no `textarea` in the DOM.

Try debugging your code on the following line:

```
<script>
      debugger;
      tinymce.init({selector:'infotextarea'});
</script>
```

When the web's execution has stopped on that line, in the development console of your browser type the following:

```
$('#infotextarea').length
```

If the size is greater than 0, textarea exists at that moment and it is another problem, but if it shows 0 is that you have not yet created that view, this will help us get more information about your problem.

Comment: thanks buddy ive got the text area to display but its only displaying as a normal text area

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target a `<textarea>` by ID you need to use a valid CSS selector.

```
selector: "#infotextarea"
```

(note the `#` at the beginning of the string)

*I would also note you appear to be loading TinyMCE 3 separate times - I have no idea why you would need to do that - loading it once should be sufficient*

Answer (score 0):

Its not a perfect answer to my question, but i used ckeditor and it worked perfectly. 
I must have a mistake somewhere that i or my team could not find with tinymce